# Android не видит USB hub

Tags: android, linux, usb

Такая проблема:
Планшет на 4.1.1 JellyBean. Есть USB-otg, клавиатура и мышь по отдельности подключаются, но одновременно через хаб нет. Когда я делаю `lsusb` то девайс говорит, что хаб есть, но мышь и клавиатура, подключённые в хаб, не работают.
Может кто сталкивался с таким. Так же внутри стоит Debian, может как то через него подключить.

Comment: Ваш hub не выставляет на шину vbus. Причин может быть несколько, начиная с банального отсутствия внешнего источника питания.

Comment: Проверил вольтаж, в первом случае без хаба 5,3 вольта, а с хабом 5 вольт. Мышь на 5 вольт, но не работает. Может ли это быть из за разницы в 0,3 вольта?

Comment: Смотрите, VBUS надо проверять на внешних для хаба портах, сам же кабель  для хаба должен занулять ID контакт.